# Error C2653. The type or namespace name could not be found (Reference present) in C++

Tags: c++, vb.net, reference

I was trying to give vb.net dll reference to C++ Project. I was able to add the reference successfully but I am unable to use it in my code.

I have following reference:

[image]

I am trying to use it like:

```
Configuration::MyClass::MyFunction()
```

I got the following error:

`error C2653: 'Configuration' : is not a class or namespace name`

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to add a header file?

Comment: Have you checked the property **Make assembly COM-Visible** in the Project Property->Assembly Information of VB.Net Project?

Comment: Hey.. i have tried this also after your suggestion.. but same scenario.. :(

Comment: May be your dll is already visible. but, your method or class may not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have exposed assembly to the COM subsystem by it's `'ComVisible'` property.  Then, you should register the assembly to expose it to COM `'subscribers'`.

Only then you can use the assembly namespace from your C++ code.

Check out [How to call a managed DLL from native Visual C++ code](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736) for step-by-step guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

Place this code at the top of the class

```
<ComVisible(True)> _
<Guid("XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX")> _
<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)> _
```

read this thread. I think this will help you. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3f30b414-2ea3-4a54-b4cb-24e48fdfda3e/calling-vbnet-dll-from-c?forum=vbgeneral

Comment: Stil not working.. Have you worked in c++? Can i show combo box from my C++ Dynamic library? external application will call my C++ dll and i want some input from combo box. Can you suggest me the best way to do this?

Comment: I have worked before in c++.but, i am not expert in this. I am a C#/VB.Net programmer. So, you want to load a combobox from your c++ dll and use it in external application. Am i right?

Comment: Hi @TithiPatel have you got your answer? I am still confused in some questions regarding vb.net dll and c++ dll. Can I talk with you in chat room in our language?

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13284066/1714730), it might be just a Visual Studio failure.

On the other hand, [the other answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15741628/1714730) that it could be a dependency issue. Also, you may have the class with the same name defined twice in different libraries.

Anyway, consider re-checking all the dependencies and the Visual Studio setup.

Here is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15322580/1714730) regarding the topic.

UPD: Check if you are not trying to define a compound namespace, which is [illegal in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4867f7c.aspx).